# How to solve this differential equation? (Steady State Solution of Forward Kolmogorov Equation)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

Here's the full question and my attempt at answering it by solving the differential equation.

Consider the following SDE
$$
d\sigma = a(\sigma,t)dt + b(\sigma,t)dW
$$
The Forward Equation (FKE) is given by
$$
\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\sigma^2}(b^2p) - \frac{\partial}{\partial\sigma}(ap)
$$

The steady state solution is given by setting $\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}=0$. Considering the boundary conditions that as $\sigma\rightarrow\infty$, $p\rightarrow 0$ and $\frac{\partial p}{\partial \sigma}\rightarrow 0$, show that the steady state solution is given by

$$
p(\sigma) = \frac{A}{b^2}e^{\int^\sigma\frac{2a}{b^2}d\sigma '}
$$

Essentially, this is a differential equation problem. Thing is, I'm stuck on how to solve it.

This is what I've got so far:

So, as per the question, the steady state solution is:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{d\sigma^2}(b^2p) - \frac{d}{d\sigma}(ap) = 0
$$

Integrating to convert to a first order differential equation?:

$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{d\sigma}(b^2p) - ap = A
$$

Given the boundary conditions in the question, $A = 0$??

$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{d\sigma}(b^2p) = ap
$$

Re-arranging we have a variable separable D.E

$$
\frac{1}{p} dp = \frac{2a}{b^2} d\sigma
$$

Integrating:

$$
\log p = \int \frac{2a}{b^2} d\sigma + D
$$

$$
p = e^{\int \frac{2a}{b^2} d\sigma + D}
$$

....and this is where I'm stuck. It looks a *little* like the expected solution but I don't know where the extra $\frac{A}{b^2}$ coefficient comes from and why there is a $d\sigma '$ in the expected solution.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $$\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{d\sigma} (b^2 \cdot p) = a \cdot p$$ you concluded $$\frac{1}{p} \, dp = \frac{2a}{b^2} \, d\sigma$$

But this is not correct: Note that $b$ does depend on $\sigma$. You have to apply the chain rule:

$$\begin{align} \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{d\sigma} (b^2 \cdot p) &= a \cdot p \\ \Rightarrow b \cdot \frac{d b}{d \sigma} \cdot p + \frac{1}{2} b^2 \cdot \frac{dp}{d \sigma} &= a \cdot p \\ \Rightarrow \frac{1}{p} \, dp &= 2 \frac{ \left(a- b \cdot \frac{db}{d\sigma}\right) }{b^2} \, d\sigma  = \frac{2a}{b^2} \, d\sigma - 2 \frac{1}{b} \cdot \frac{db}{d\sigma} \, d\sigma \end{align}$$

From the second term on the righthand-side you obtain the factor $\frac{1}{b^2}$ in the given solution.

Concerning $d\sigma'$: Since $p=p(\sigma)$ you shouldn't use $\sigma$ as variable of integration at the same time. That's why they called it $\sigma'$ instead (has nothing to do with the derivative!).

Comment: Thanks a lot Saz, that's a huge help. My algebra is pretty poor so I'm still not sure how the A comes in though.

Comment: So integrating $2\frac{1}{b}\frac{db}{d\sigma}d\sigma$ becomes $2\log b + C$

Comment: @user62066 The constant $A$ comes from $e^{D}$. (Note that $e^{x+y} = e^x \cdot e^y$.)

And yes, it becomes $-2 \cdot \log b = \log(b^{-2})$ (you can omit the constant $C$, because you already have the integrating constant $D$). And you still have to apply the exponential function (on both sides of the equation; after integrating).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Saz, apparently this isn't the right answer. When the question says "show that the steady state solution is given by..." it means you have to show that the equation given satisfies the PDE. Do you think you could help me get started on this one?

Comment: @FredBlogs Where are you stuck? Since $p$ is given, you only have to calculate the derivatives (with respect to $\sigma$) and plug them into the equation to show that this is indeed a solution of the given equation.

Comment: Yep, so where I'm stuck is calculating the derivatives - it's the $ \sigma' $ that I'm not sure about, I suppose. For example $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial\sigma} (ap) = \frac{\partial}{\partial\sigma} \frac{aA}{b^2} e^{\int \frac{2a}{b^2} d\sigma}$$

Comment: Doesn't that just become zero? So, the equation becomes 0= 0-0? This doesn't seem right. I'm out of practice with partial differentiation so perhaps that's where I'm lost. What is the first step?

Comment: This is driving me nuts! I'm sure the solution is simple but I just don't know how to go about it. You say I have to calculate the derivatives with respect to $\sigma$? If you could help me get started calculating the first derivative, that would be appreciated. $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial\sigma} (ap) = a.\frac{\partial p}{\partial\sigma} + \frac{\partial a}{\partial\sigma}.p $$

Comment: @FredBlogs The last equation is correct. Since $p(\sigma) = \frac{A}{b(\sigma,t)^2} \cdot e^{\int_0^\sigma \frac{2a}{b^2} \, d\sigma'}$ you have $$\frac{\partial p}{\partial \sigma} = A \cdot \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma} \frac{1}{b^2} \right) \cdot e^{\ldots} + \frac{A}{b^2} \cdot \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma} e^{\ldots} \right) = \left( -2 \frac{A}{b^3} \cdot \frac{\partial b}{\partial \sigma} + \frac{2a}{b^2} \right) \cdot e^{\ldots}$$ $(e^{\ldots} = e^{\int_0^\sigma \frac{2a}{b^2} \, d\sigma'}$)

Answer (score 1):

Note that the boundary conditions
$$\sigma\rightarrow\infty\Rightarrow\left\{\begin{array}{c}p\rightarrow 0\\ \frac{\partial p}{\partial\sigma}\rightarrow 0\end{array}\right.$$

Are **not** enough to state
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\sigma}(b^2p)-(ap)=A=0$$

Because, as $b$ is a function of $\sigma$,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\sigma}(b^2p) = 2b\frac{\partial b}{\partial\sigma}p+b^2\frac{\partial p}{\partial\sigma}$$

And you will also need that, as $\sigma\rightarrow \infty$, that
$$\begin{array}{c}bp\frac{\partial b}{\partial\sigma}\rightarrow 0\\b^2\frac{\partial p}{\partial\sigma}\rightarrow 0 \end{array}$$
as well to get $A=0$.